# az cli creating deployment slot returning "unauthorised. develop"

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am a subscription owner,
I have an azure app service which is a web app for windows containers.
I can log in through the azure portal, and create a deployment slot through the UI without any issue.
However when I login through the azure cli, and try to use the following command to create a new deployment slot, I get a 403 error with a slightly odd message:

```
 az webapp deployment slot create --name "foo-dev" --resource-group development --slot test --debug
```

I see it fail, with the following in the debug log output:

> adal-python : XXXX - CacheDriver:Looking for potential cache entries: {'_clientId': '...', 'userId': '...'}
>   adal-python : XXXX  - CacheDriver:Found 2 potential entries.
>   adal-python : XXXX  - CacheDriver:Resource specific token found.
>   adal-python : dXXXX  - CacheDriver:Returning token from cache lookup, AccessTokenId: b'XXXX ', RefreshTokenId: b'XXXX '
>   msrest.http_logger : Request URL: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/development/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/foo-dev/slots/test?api-version=2019-08-01'
>   msrest.http_logger : Request method: 'PUT'
>   msrest.http_logger : Request headers:
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Accept': 'application/json'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'accept-language': 'en-US'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Length': '368'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'User-Agent': 'python/3.6.6 (Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0) msrest/0.6.13 msrest_azure/0.6.3 azure-mgmt-web/0.44.0 Azure-SDK-For-Python AZURECLI/2.4.0 (MSI)'
>   msrest.http_logger : Request body:
>   msrest.http_logger : {"location": "West Europe", "properties": {"serverFarmId": "/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/Development/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/foo-dev", "reserved": false, "isXenon": false, "hyperV": false, "siteConfig": {"netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6", "localMySqlEnabled": false, "http20Enabled": true}, "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false}}
>   msrest.universal_http : Configuring redirects: allow=True, max=30
>   msrest.universal_http : Configuring request: timeout=100, verify=True, cert=None
>   msrest.universal_http : Configuring proxies: ''
>   msrest.universal_http : Evaluate proxies against ENV settings: True
>   urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/development/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/foo-dev/slots/test?api-version=2019-08-01 HTTP/1.1" 401 372
>   msrest.http_logger : Response status: 401
>   msrest.http_logger : Response headers:
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'ETag': '"XXXX"'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-resource-requests': '499'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-request-id': 'XXXX'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-correlation-request-id': 'f17fd4c0-51a0-4ae1-b869-396bf92e495f'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'UKSOUTH:20200422T082226Z:f17fd4c0-51a0-4ae1-b869-396bf92e495f'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Date': 'Wed, 22 Apr 2020 08:22:26 GMT'
>   msrest.http_logger :     'Connection': 'close'
>   msrest.http_logger : Response content:
>   msrest.http_logger : {"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"Access is denied. Not authorized. develop","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Access is denied. Not authorized. develop"},{"Code":"Unauthorized"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"01001","MessageTemplate":"Access is denied.","Parameters":[],"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"Access is denied. Not
>   authorized. develop"}}],"Innererror":null}
>   msrest.exceptions : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
>   cli.azure.cli.core.util : Access is denied. Not authorized. develop
>   Access is denied. Not authorized. develop
>   az_command_data_logger : exit code: 1
>   telemetry.save : Save telemetry record of length 2540 in cache

I've replaced any sensitive values with XXXX in the output above.
This message seems odd to me: "Access is denied. Not authorized. develop"

Why the word "develop"? AFAIK that word doesn't relate to any of my named resources - i.e that doesn't correspond to the app name or the name of the resource group it's in (development) so it just seems odd to see that tacked on.. what does "develop" relate to here?

I can execute the list deployment slot command with the cli and that works fine.

UPDATE:
 - The same error occurs in Azure Cloud Shell
 - Yes the error is still happening (30th April 2020)

Comment: This error is odd, can you try again by using Azure cloud shell? You can start the shell in  Azure portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZUxm.png

Comment: I didn't encounter this error, can you confirm if this issue still exist?

Comment: @TonyJu - yes it still exists, I just repeated it using az cli version  2.4.0

Comment: @TonyJu - and yes the same error also occurs with azure cloud shell.

Answer (score 0):

Please login in Azure portal and open Azure cloud Shell.

[image]

Run `az account show` command to confirm the account you logged in. If this account is your subscription owner, and the same error occurs, you need to raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).